# Google API - Distance Matrix vs Directiction Objective-C

Tags: ios7, google-api

I am writing an iOS app that determines the best route between a set of addresses. I am currently using the Google Distance Matrix. I can successfully send a request but after sending it 1 origin and 2 destinations, it returns null.

```
NSString *address0 = @"111 Main St City ST 55555";
NSString *address1 = @"222 Main St City ST 5555";
NSString *address2 = @"333 Main St City ST 5555";

NSString *escAddress0 = [address0 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *escAddress1 = [address1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *escAddress2 = [address2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%@&destinations=%@|%@&language=en-EN&key={APIKEY}", escAddress0,escAddress1,escAddress2];

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:request] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"result: %@ ", result)
```

;

Is the Directions API a better choice for something like this? And is there a good reason it would return null. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? I am a bit of a novice at using services and APIs